# Using a method reverse to sorted list gives error

Tags: python-3.x, list

Hi I have a list of places

```
>>> places = ['NYC','PA', 'SF', 'Vienna', 'Berlin', 'Amsterdam']
```

I temporarily sort it with

```
>>> sorted(places)
```

And finally I want to sort the sorted(places) list in reverse alphabetical order.

Is this ever correct?

```
>>> sorted(places).reverse()
```

I thought it was but Python3 says the list is none.

Thank you

Comment: Do `reversed(sorted(places))`. The `.reverse()` method reverses a list in-place without returning anything, just like the `.sort()` method sorts it in-place without returning anything. You may also have to do `list(reversed(sorted(places)))`, because `reversed()` returns a generator that needs to be casted to list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll probably use more variables to ease the flow of the code, at least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are a few examples how you can do it:

your list:

```
places = ['NYC','PA', 'SF', 'Vienna', 'Berlin', 'Amsterdam']
```

using *sort method with reverse* parameter

```
places.sort(reverse=True)
print(places)
```

using *sorted and reverse methods on a new variable* since sorted method would require one:

```
testlist=sorted(places)
testlist.reverse()
print(testlist)
```

using *sorted method with reverse* parameter:

```
testlist1=sorted(places, reverse=True)
print(testlist1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(sorted(places,reverse=True))
```

or you can use a variable

```
other_list=sorted(places,reverse=True)
print(other_list)
```